# Display item on click on ListView

Tags: android, listview, dialog

I need help on a specific task :

I have a `ListView` in my main activity with a custom `Adapter` associated, and an `OnItemLongClick` listener that displays a `Dialog` with many operations configured (change quantity, cancel item...) and it works like a charm.

My goal is to have a physical copy of the clicked item in the `Dialog`, to display immediately the changes made.

Since my ListView item is complex and designed by the `Adapter`, i can't just get the reference to the original object, i need a visual copy of the selected ListView item...

I thought about creating the same structure (`ListView` and `Adapter`) with only the selected item associated but it's kind of heavy...

Is there a simpler solution that can help me in this situation ? I mean real copy of the original ListView Item with changes made in my `Dialog` done to the original object...

Comment: plz elaborate `physical copy of the clicked item`....

Comment: what is physical copy of item? never heard of :)

Comment: i meant a copy that is resembling and referencing the same object source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting your relavent code may help us to guide you more clearly.

However you can get your object in `onItemLongClick((AdapterView, View, int position, long)` using `position` params i.e

```
YourObject objReference = yourActivityClassObjectList.get(position);
```

now when showing dialog, pass this `objReference` to your dialog and when changes made, change the contents of this `objReference` and call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

instead of passing the `objReference` to dialog, you can pass `int position` and while changes made, get the reference to that object, change contents and notify data set changed to Adapter.

Comment: thank you. I combined my thought with your hint, and ended with a new adapter on a new ListView inside my Dialog displaying the copy of the object AND a link to the original adapter to use the procedures on the original adapter, then i use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); on both adapters and everything works like i wanted !

Answer (score 1):

When you click on one listview item the [onListItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) callback should be fired. As you see in the doc the third parameter is `position`. You can call `YourAdapter.getItem(int)` to retrive the element hold by the `listview` at `position`